AxiosError 'Request failed with status code 404', code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST' on reactjs
I'm practing user authentication and Login in reactjs.
I'm having this error when accessing the home route, '/', however it does not seem to come up when I'm accessing any other routes. By default, the home route should redirect to login page, which works on Edge but not on Firefox, even though I still get the error on both browsers.
I setup react with Vite by the way
This is the Home.jsx file
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { useCookies } from "react-cookie";
import axios from "axios";
import { ToastContainer, toast } from "react-toastify";
import "../App.css";


const Home = () => {
    const navigate = useNavigate()
    const [cookies, removeCookie] = useCookies([]);
    const [username, setUsername] = useState('')

    useEffect(() => {
        const verifyCookie = async () => {
            if (!cookies.token) {
                navigate("/login")
            }

            const { data } = await axios.post(
                "http://localhost:5173",
                {},
                { withCredentials: true }
            ).then(response => {
                // Handle successful response
                console.log(response.data)
            });

            const { status, user } = data;
            setUsername(user)
            return status
                ? toast(`Hello ${user}`, { position: "top-right" })
                : (removeCookie("token"), navigate('/login'))
        }
        verifyCookie();
    }, [cookies, navigate, removeCookie])


    const Logout = () => {
        removeCookie("token");
        navigate("/signup");
    };

    return (
        <>
            <div className="home_page">
                <h4>
                    {" "}
                    Welcome <span>{username}</span>
                </h4>
                <button onClick={Logout}>LOGOUT</button>
            </div>
            <ToastContainer />
        </>
    );
}
export default Home

This is the server, although I'm not sure that may be the problem
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt')
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser")
require('dotenv').config();


const app = express();

const classRoutes = require('./routes/classRoutes')
const authRoute = require("./routes/AuthRoutes");

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4000;

mongoose.connection.on('connected', () => {
    console.log('Connected to MongoDB Atlas');
});

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cookieParser());


app.use('/api', classRoutes)
app.use("/api", authRoute);

const atlasConnectionUri = process.env.MONGODB_URL;
mongoose.connect(atlasConnectionUri, {
    dbName: 'subjects'
});

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    const __dirname = path.resolve();
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/dist"))

    app.get('*', (req, res) => {
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dist', 'index.html'));
    });
} else {
    app.get('/', (req, res) => {
        res.send("Hello");
    })
}   

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server is Running at ${PORT}`);
});

I thought it was a cors error, so I tried installing the cors dependencies and linking it to my backend. But it didn't work.
My server is running on a port 4000, and my react with vite is running on port 5173 and it's been working fine thus far.

If you say the express is working on 4000, so you've to target the localhost:4000 not 5173. Try with 4000.

It didn't work. That even brings up the CORS errror

Apparently, making submissions on the signup and login give the same error too

Your idea worked, but not exactly. I assigned app.use('/api), so all my routes to backend require '/api' to be added after the http address.
So just adding the '/api' before the respective routes fixed all the errors
